# HTML Table Formatting - Dynamic Column Widths based on content

Tags: html, html-table, css-tables

I am working on an HTML file that I will use as both an attachment to an email and the basis for an HTML based email message that has a table with 13 columns.

I would like to have the columns auto size based on the contents so that columns with shorter headings and values do not take up as much space as longer valued columns. Right now I am seeing that all the columns are evenly sized.

Here is my current CSS and table code snippets

```css
     /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
     table, td {
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
     }
 
     /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
     table {
         border-spacing: 0 !important;
         border-collapse: collapse !important;
         table-layout: fixed !important;
         margin: 0 auto !important;
     }
 
     table table table {
         table-layout: auto;
     }
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" style="font-size:10pt;table-layout: fixed;">
       <thead style="background-color:#10163C;color:#FFFFFF">
         <tr>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Evaluation End Date<br/>(11:59 PM)</th>
            <th>Days<br/>Remaining</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Catalog</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Trait</th>
            <th>Instructor</th>
            <th>Responses</th>
            <th>Enrollment</th>
            <th>Response<br/>Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Fall 2020</td>
            <td>December 9, 2020</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>SUBJ</td>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td>MWE</td>
            <td>Class_Long NAme Goes Here</td>
            <td>UGRD</td>
            <td>Online</td>
            <td>Y Teacher</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0.00%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

In the example the Semester, Days Remaining, Subject, Catalog, Section, Level, Trait, Responses, Enrollment, Response Rate columns should be narrower as they have short values.

While the Evaluation End Date and Course Name should be wider as their values are longer.

One limitation is that I cannot use JavaScript/JQuery as I am using email to send these out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

You can apply a `min-width` on the `th` and set the width to `100%` like this:

```
th {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 125px;
}
```

Additionally, I removed the fixed layout specification because it was preventing some styles from being applied to the table.

```css
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */

table,
td {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}


/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */

table {
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1" style="font-size:10pt;">
    <thead style="background-color:#10163C;color:#FFFFFF">
      <tr style="background-color:#10163C;color:#FFFFFF">
        <th>Semester</th>
        <th>Evaluation End Date<br/>(11:59 PM)</th>
        <th>Days<br/>Remaining</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Catalog</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Course Name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Trait</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Responses</th>
        <th>Enrollment</th>
        <th>Response<br/>Rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Fall 2020</td>
        <td>December 9, 2020</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>SUBJ</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>MWE</td>
        <td>Class_Long NAme Goes Here</td>
        <td>UGRD</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>Y Teacher</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0.00%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is another solution if you don't want to set widths:

```css
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */

table,
td {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}


/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */

table {
  border-spacing: 0 !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1" style="font-size:10pt;">
    <thead style="background-color:#10163C;color:#FFFFFF">
      <tr style="background-color:#10163C;color:#FFFFFF">
        <th>Semester</th>
        <th>Evaluation End Date<br/>(11:59 PM)</th>
        <th>Days<br/>Remaining</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Catalog</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Course Name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Trait</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Responses</th>
        <th>Enrollment</th>
        <th>Response<br/>Rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Fall 2020</td>
        <td>December 9, 2020</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>SUBJ</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>MWE</td>
        <td>Class_Long NAme Goes Here</td>
        <td>UGRD</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>Y Teacher</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0.00%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

All I did was add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `th` element.

Comment: When I tried your solution, the columns did not resize (except for the first column and that column only resizes bigger if I widen the window)

Comment: Did you run the snippet above?

Comment: Yes and even in the code snippet it only resizes the first column.

Comment: Also included an alternate solution below my original answer. You can add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `th` element.

Comment: Still no change. I even reduced the number of columns and it did not change.

Comment: Are you still using code from your original question or the updated code I provided in my answer? - Some of your original styles will prevent it from working.

Comment: Tried Both versions.